# dotdotdot - Wrap text at the first full stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotdotdot

I am trying to cut off the text at the first full stop using dotdotdot plugin. However I can't make it work. I tried `word-wrap: break-word;` but it didn't work. How to cut off the text at the first full stop?

I've set these options:

```
$("#wrapper").dotdotdot({
 wrap: 'word',
 watch: true,
 ellipsis: '...',
 fallbackToLetter: false,
  lastCharacter : {
    remove: [ ',', ';'],
    noEllipsis: ['.']
 },
});
```

**[My example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2z6Xa/752/)**

Comment: Is there a reason you need a plugin?  `x.substring(0, x.indexOf(".")+1);`

Comment: I am considering the possibility of not having a full stop in the sentence. So If there is a full stop then cut the text, otherwise add the ellipsis. Does that make sense?

Comment: You are using version 1.2.1. Latest version is 1.8.3. Maybe that options was not imlemented. Only guessing, not tried.

Comment: Oh sorry that was the fiddle. Yeah I looked into their docs but couldn't find that option there.

Comment: *Stop at full stop if there is one, otherwise add '...'*.  No, makes no possible use/scenario sense to me.  If the text is 10,000chars long but with a "." at the end, it won't truncate?  But if it's "Hi. How goes it" it truncates at "Hi."?

Comment: I wasn't very clear. Stop at full stop if there is one, otherwise after 20 characters add '...' and no, the component that I am working on wont't have that kind of sentence "Hi. How it goes?" in any possible way.

Comment: No worries.  Contrived examples to illustrate the point.  Truncate to first full stop or apply ellipses.   The [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) plugin doesn't do "after 20 characters", it does fit-to-content (which is generally better for UI).  So if you need 20 chars max, you'll need to look elsewhere.   It also doesn't provide a mechanism to "override" the truncation as it does complicted stuff to ensure valid html.  If you know your text doesn't include html and you want 20 max or less if full stop, then you'll be better off writing your own in a few lines or another plugin.

Comment: Yeah that make sense. I will add that piece of functionality to count the characters.